# Python cleaning values to int

Tags: python, int

A JSON endpoint returns values that I want to convert to ints to save in a DB (mysql).

The values can come back in the following formats:

- 100000
- 100,000
- 100.000
- 100 000
- 100000.00
- 100,000.00
- 100.000,00
- 100 000.00
- N/A

I am new to python, and can't figure out how to handle each case.  I've tried:

```
int(value) if value != 'N/A' else None
```

Which handles N/A but throws a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10` for anything that isn't locally formated

```
local.atoi(value) if value != 'N/A' else None
```

Handles all the values with commas but throws a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:` for anything with a float or anything with periods instead of commas as thousand separators.

How can I catch and clean all the integer formats?

Comment: What type is the JSON passing to python?

Comment: Are the digits separated by commas and the decimal portion is always separated by a period, or do you need to be locale aware for that ?

Comment: So, is `100.000` supposed to be `100` or `100000`? What about `100.000.00`? Frankly, that format is terrible.

Comment: is `100 000` supposed to be `100`? Or `100000`?

Comment: Ok, actually... Would you mind taking all your examples and putting them into a code block in the format `input   ==>   output`?

Comment: I agree the inconsistent format is terrible, i believe 100.000 is supposed to be the italian format or 100 000

Comment: You... Don't actually know what a given value should map to?

Comment: nope... if you want to see the data GET https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist , I'm looking at the TotalCoinSupply key

Comment: If those are currencies, there's probably a specialized module for parsing those, provided that you have to locale for each entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part seems to be differentiating decimal points and thousands separators, as some of the numbers seem to use a `.` for both. But it seems like numbers have either zero, or two decimal places, so we can use this strip away the decimal part (which is not needed for `int` anyway).

```
>>> nums = ["100000","100,000","100.000","100 000","100000.00","100,000.00","100.000.00","100 000.00"]
>>> [re.sub(r"[.,]\d{2}$", "", n) for n in nums]
['100000', '100,000', '100.000', '100 000', '100000', '100,000', '100.000', '100 000']
```

Afterwards, just remove any non-digit-characters and convert to `int`.

```
>>> [int(re.sub(r"[ ,.]", "", n)) for n in _]
[100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000, 100000]
```

Just wrap those to `re.sub` operations into a function, together with the `if` check for `N/A`.

---

If you know the locale of those numbers, you could also try the `locale` or `babel` modules:

```
>>> import babel.numbers
>>> babel.numbers.parse_decimal("100,000.000", "en")
Decimal('100000.000')
>>> babel.numbers.parse_decimal("100,000.000", "de")
Decimal('100.000000')
```

Those return `Decimal` numbers, which can easily be converted to `int`. If you *don't* know the locale, and can't guarantee a fixed/maximum number of decimal places, I don't see how you could ever decide whether e.g. `100.000` is supposed to be `100` or `100000`.

Comment: It's trivial, but you forgot to account for the possible value 'N/A'

Comment: @JakobLovern That's exactly why I did not mention it. The only way to cover that is with an explicit if/else, which OP already did.

Comment: there can be any number of decimal places, sorry I just used two as an example

Comment: @WindDude Then how do you know what `100.000` is supposed to be?

Comment: That is actually true, that I couldn't know with 100% certainty what the value of 100.000 is supposed to be.  And that might be partially why i'm so stuck, because locale.atoi or locale.atof need to be passed in int of float, so I'm stuck on how to parse it to either an int or float consistently first.

Comment: @tobias_k thanks i'm looking at the bable parse_decimal and how to determine what locale the number is.

Comment: or a best best guess of what locale the number is formatted in.

Comment: But i don't think it is possible because as tobias_k mentioned there is no way to know if a number returned as 999,999 or 999.999 is supposed to be int(999999) or float(999.999) without knowing the locale, and for the same reason a locale can't be determined from the returned number.  I accepted this answer because it illuminated to this fact.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all the characters like spaces and commas up front, then parse as a `float` (for values that are not `N/A`):

```
f = None if s == 'N/A' else float(s.translate(str.maketrans({' ': None, ',', None})))
```

What you do with the resulting `float` is up to you after that. If you trust the number to always be an integer, convert it directly:

```
i = int(f)
```

If you don't trust the input, check if it is an integer first (but the process will basically be the same anyway):

```
i = int(f)
if i != f:
    # Handle the error
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to parse this manually to take out the ambiguity. For example, in `100,000`, can the comma indicate a decimal point? Some countries use a comma instead of a decimal point.

And what is this supposed to mean anyway: `100.000.00`?

If you can assume that no commas are decimal points and that multiple points can be ignored then you can try the following:
    def fitler_na(value):
        return value.lower().replace('n/a')

```
def filter_spaces(value):
    return value.replace(' ')

def filter_commas(value):
    return value.replace(',', '')

def filter_multiple_points(value):
    if value.count('.') > 1:
        return value.replace('.', '')
    else:
        return value

filters = [filter_na, filter_spaces, filter_commas, filter_multiple_points]
```

Then you can apply the list of filters to your values:

```
values = ['100,000', '100,000.00', '100 000.00', '100.500.000', 'N/A']
for idx, value in enumerate(values):
    for f in filters:
        values[idx] = f(values[idx])
    values[idx] = round(values[idx])
```

Comment: I believe I made a mistake with 100.000.00 it should be 100.000,00, I've updated my original question to reflect this

Comment: Same difference. You're still going to have to explicitly decide for every possible case which character represents a decimal and which not. If the comma is a decimal point, you have to replace it with '.' before converting or rounding to int.